# roswtf - expansion

Tags: ros, roswtf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As silly as it might sound, what does roswtf expand to?

Is it what I think it is?

:P

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/186791/roswtf---expansion/) by [McMurdo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1973/mcmurdo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1247 on 2014-07-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes it is.

---

Originally posted by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) with karma: 2949 on 2014-07-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1